# can't write command on git bash after writing --list command on Windows7

Tags: git-bash

I'm newly trying to learn git. After commanding `git config --list` I am not able to write other command.

I then frequently pressed enter and it then shows an `END` message.

I want to write a clear command. What can I do now?

[image: command prompt]

Comment: `ctrl + X` is exit, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit from [GNU/Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix) if you don't know what GNU/Less is. `git config --list` uses GNU/Less to allow you to see above of the output that you can see.